# Bad Font Scaling in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I scale the code editor in Visual Studio 2015 it makes the font blurry instead of properly scaling it. I'm using the default font (Consolas). Changing the font size in the settings works, however, that's not a solution for me as I tend to change the font frequently based on how much code I need to see at once (for some reason I generally prefer bigger font).

I have not used VS for about a month, and so I may have installed something that messed it up or something.

Here's what I'm talking about:
[100% scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJWyn.png) (fine)
[200% scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HBpK.png) (blurry)